# Remove identical files in UNIX

Tags: shell, file, unix, duplicates

I'm dealing with a large amount (30,000) files of about 10MB in size. Some of them (I estimate 2%) are actually duplicated, and I need to keep only a copy for every duplicated pair (or triplet).
Would you suggest me an efficient way to do that? I'm working on unix.

Comment: Duplicate can be based on the following
1. content
2. filename

how do you want to do?

Comment: Content :-)
Based on filename would be too easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an existing tool for this: fdupes

Restoring a solution from an old deleted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a script to create a hash of every file. You could store the hashes in a set, iterate over the files, and where a file hashes to a value already found in the set, delete the file. This would be trivial to do in Python, for example.

For 30,000 files, at 64 bytes per hash table entry, you're only looking at about 200 megabytes.

Comment: What's a metabyte? Some sort of idealised byte? And your solution only works if you have  a perfect hash function.

Comment: What *isn't* a metabyte? Fixed. The paranoid could compare the contents of the files in the case of deleting. Adding an extra hash could also help.

Comment: @Neil If you use a modern, currently unbroken cryptographic hash function and you find a collision, your algorithm breaks down but you have gained a cryptographic paper, so it's all win. It is worth comparing the supposed duplicates before erasing one of them, though.

Comment: Proper cryptographic hash functions are not perfect by a simple counting argument, but you can treat them as they were for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @Pascal There certainly can be a collision. Consider that a file can be seen as a very large single binary number, much larger than the hash. Collisions are thus inevitable, because the hash loses information.

Answer (score 2):

Find possible duplicate files:

```
find DIR -type f -exec sha1sum "{}" \; | sort | uniq -d -w40
```

Now you can use `cmp` to check that the files are really identical.

Comment: -w is a feature of gnu uniq; -d will only find consecutive duplicates, so you'd have to sort first

Comment: Instead of using `-w` (which is only in GNU, like the first comment said) you can pipe the output of `sort` to `cut -d \  -f 1` and then pipe that to `uniq -d`. This is more portable. It will work on BSD, OS X, and other systems.

Comment: @monokrome: Err ... no. That would just give you the checksums without the file names. If don't have GNU `uniq`, you'll have to use `awk` and it's associative arrays to simulate `uniq`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this snippet to get all duplicates first before removing.

```
find /path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha512sum | awk '($1 in seen){print "duplicate: "$2" and "seen[$1] }(!($1 in  seen)){seen[$1]=$2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a script that first compares file sizes, then MD5 checksums (caching them, of course) and, if you're very anxious about losing data, bites the bullet and actually compares duplicate candidates byte for byte. If you have no additional knowledge about how the files came to be etc., it can't really be done much more efficiently.

Comment: It's a high-througput download from different sources, so I got some redundancy.
I'll try md5sum, so I should get a hashcode for all of them. I'll let you know if it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Save all the file names in an array. Then traverse the array. In each iteration, compare the file contents with the other file's contents by using the command `md5sum`. If the MD5 is the same, then remove the file.

For example, if file `b` is a duplicate of file `a`, the `md5sum` will be the same for both the files.

Comment: you might want to consider the algorithmical complexity of that particular approach...